# incompatible types for redefinition C error

Tags: c

I have a function that takes two arrays as input and modifies the first one. I am getting an error `error: incompatible types for redefinition of 'applyChange'`on the first line:

```
void applyChange(int values[3][3][3], int changeCode[9]){
```

I checked and I didn't accidentally try to define the function twice. I also made sure I am calling it properly (i.e. correct inputs and not expecting a return value).

EDIT:

```
void hillClimb(int values[3][3][3],int pastData[20]){

  int bestVal = evaluateValues(values,pastData);
  int bestCode[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

  int valueChangeCode[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  int valuesCopy[3][3][3];
  //copyValues(valuesCopy,values);

  while (incrementBaseThree(valueChangeCode,9)){
    copyValues(valuesCopy,values);
    applyChange(valuesCopy,valueChangeCode);
    int evaluation = evaluateValues(valuesCopy,pastData);
    if (evaluation > bestVal) {
      bestVal = evaluation;
      copyChangeCode(bestCode,valueChangeCode);
    }
  }
  applyChange(values,bestCode);

}

void applyChange(int values[3][3][3], int changeCode[9]){

  for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++){
    changeCode[a] --;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
      values[i][k][ (0+k) % 3 ] += changeCode[ (3*i) + 0];
      values[i][k][ (1+k) % 3 ] += changeCode[ (3*i) + 1];
      values[i][k][ (2+k) % 3 ] += changeCode[ (3*i) + 2];
    }
  }

  for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++){//we need this so that we don't mess up changeCode in the upper stack frame
    changeCode[a] ++;
  }

}
```

copyValues and copyChangeCode just duplicate the values in the respective arrays.

Comment: What's the full error message? Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you have any other compile errors?  Like for example, if your function is called before its definition it's function signature is assumed, and that assumption is usually wrong.

Comment: Is there a function prototype somewhere?

Comment: Maybe the function prototype does not match the function declaration implementation from your code above.

Comment: there are no other compiler errors. the full error message is just: `main.c:72: error: incompatible types for redefinition of 'aplChange'`. I am using TCC.

Comment: @hexidian: How does your function call looks like? Do you have defined a function prototype somewhere?

Comment: Well move from TCC to the 21st century please.

Comment: huh? can you try and keep your comments productive, Weather Vane. I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @WeatherVane According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) the latest version is from December of 2017. Not old by any means.

Comment: SHOW ALL YOUR CODE

Comment: I'm doing this from my home windows PC. I use TCC because it was the easiest to install. Do you think that a different compiler would fix the error?

Comment: @hexidian: The compiler shouldn't be the problem, but please post some more code. We can't help you with the single code line from above.

Comment: an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be most helpful

Comment: And how is `valueChangeCode` defined? On which line is the function `applyChange()` defined and on which line to you call the function? The function have to be defined above the function call.

Comment: what information do you think is missing from my examples? I'm not sure how much you want.

Comment: something we can copy and paste and compile and get your same error

Comment: which bit of SHOW ALL YOUR CODE is not clear

Comment: applyChange is defined on line 72 (the line referenced in the error message). It is called in line 179.

Comment: sorry pm100. I am getting a lot of responses and I wasn't replying to yours specifically. If you want to see all of the code it is at https://github.com/hexidian/RockPaperScissorsNeuralNet I don't want to just copy and paste all of it.

Comment: valueChangeCode is defined: `int valueChangeCode[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` and then the array is modified, but is always 9 elements that are either 0,1, or 2.

Comment: that code in github has nothign called applyChange

Comment: Don't post all of your code. Post a [mcve]. Click the link to see what you need to do.

Comment: Your code on github shows only 106 lines. But you said you call the function on line 179. And also there is no function like `applyChange()`.

Comment: "ALL YOUR CODE" is a little overzealous. Nobody wants to see all your code. We want to see an MCVE that duplicates the problem. That does mean some extra work on your part. You will probably find the problem yourself when creating one.

Comment: sorry pm100, I hadn't pushed it. It should be up now.

Comment: As of C99, calling a function with no visible declaration is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic. Many C compilers will issue a warning (which qualifies as a diagnostic) and then apply the old pre-C99 rules, implicitly declaring the function as if it returned `int`. This can result in confusing error and warning messages. You didn't declare `applyChange` twice, but under the old rules you did so implicitly. Never ignore warnings, and always include the full text of all warning and error messages in the body of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now that you have posted your code.

you need to declare `applyChange()` *before* you call it.

put

```
void applyChange(int values[3][3][3], int changeCode[9]);
```

at the top of the file

Comment: and dont ignore compiler warnings - they are there to help yo. You almost certainly got a warning on the calls to applyChange

Comment: I didn't get a warning. TCC is extremely minimalist, and I think it would be best to start using a better compiler, especially as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `applyChange()` on line 61 and 68. But the function is defined in line 72. Thus the compiler doesn't know the `applyChange()` function in line 61 or 68.

**You have now two options:**

1.) Put the function `applyChange()` above your function call.

2.) Add a function prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include a prototype for `applyChange` in a header file. I'm guessing what's happening is that the compiler is getting to the function call before the function definition and is inferring a signature that conflicts with the actual signature.

Comment: My program is only in one file and the main() is at the bottom. If you think there could still be an error despite that, I'll do it.

Comment: We'll be able to help more if you provide a complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hexidian: As Turn mentioned, you should give us a complete example. Otherwise we can't detect why you're getting the error above.